# Spells placing effects on heroic

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-heroic

I know this may really sound dumb for asking, but..
Say you have a card like [Dragonrage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dragonrage) and it applies onto say [Favored Hoplite](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Favored%20Hoplite).

I know the Dragonrage's affect will trigger Heroic, but the "R: This creature gains +1/+0" wouldnt affect Heroic if used correct since it isn't technically a spell right?

Answer (score 10):

> I know the Dragonrage's affect will trigger Heroic...

Actually, it doesn't. The word "target" doesn't appear anywhere on Dragonrage, and it's not an aura, so it doesn't target, and so it doesn't trigger heroic.

As an alternative example, [Dragon Mantle](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dragon%20Mantle) is an aura, so it does trigger heroic when you initially cast it.

> the "R: This creature gains +1/+0" wouldn't affect Heroic if used correct since it isn't technically a spell right?

Right. This is an activated ability, not a spell. Additionally, it doesn't target, so even if it was a spell, it wouldn't trigger heroic anyway.